# Is there any another way to configure Firestore with Php without recommendation of grpc extention?

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore, grpc

Is there any other way to configure Firestore with Php without recommendation of grpc extension?

My Server is not supported grpc extension. Server contains centOs and RHEL6 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You can try either of the following:*

> 1. **Github repository: [Firestore PHP Client without gRCP extension](https://github.com/ahsankhatri/firestore-php)**
> 2. **Packagist - The PHP Package Repository: [Firestore SDK for PHP without gRPC](https://packagist.org/packages/morrislaptop/firestore-php)**
> 3. **Github Repository: [Firestore SDK for PHP without gRPC](https://github.com/morrislaptop/firestore-php)**

Comment: thank you i am using the last one reference which you have provide it is really helpful.

Comment: but using your repository i'am unable to fire some queries like Where() is not define .so can you help me out to fixing this.

Comment: Hi @Vaibhavbuccha, it sounds like you may need to add the Cloud Firestore PHP library to your app. Just like this:
`composer require google/cloud-firestore`. Check out this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) for further reference

Answer (score 1):

### Firestore Client for PHP without gRPC

The ahsankhatri/firestore-php package has been archived and wasn't compatible with php 8.  A [newer fork of that project](https://github.com/bensontrent/firestore-php) has been published with support for Guzzle 7 and is compatible with PHP 7 & 8.

You can install it with:

```
composer require bensontrent/firestore-php
```